# cordova plugin background mode plugin - 'backgroundMode' of undefined

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file, background-mode

Is there any complete sample about cordova plugin background mode?

I am get error 'backgroundMode' of undefined

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue. Just got it solved.

I would advise you not to follow the Ionic Documentation.

Use the following code in CLI to install the plugin.

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git`

Then in your `ionViewDidLoad()` of the root of your app, you can write the following code:

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();//Line 1
    console.log("BackgroundMode is Enabled!");//Line 2
    console.log(cordova.plugins.backgroundMode);//Line 3
}
```

Before this, you should declare `cordova` by following code after all your imports.

`declare let cordova:any;`

This one should help :)